# Cassandra daemon automatically stops

Tags: linux, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I'm starting the Cassandra daemon and it stays up for 10 seconds and then it stops working automatically. What would be the problem here?

[Cassandra daemon automatically stops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Idiop.png)

Comment: What does the system.log say?  Also it's better to post your messages as text and not images (text is searchable).